# Find last time a word was said

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am attempting to make a bot that can track the length of time between when a word was last said and once it is said again. For example, if someone said "hello" 16 hours ago and someone says it again, then I want the bot to respond once the message is sent stating that "hello" was said 16 hours ago. Below I have my attempt at reading the previous messages to find the text, but I haven't gotten it to work... I have not yet started to try and make a timer because I haven't been able to get this to work.

```
 bot.channels.get('712147984464478251');
   channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 1}).then(messages => {
        let lastMessage = messages.first();

        if(!lastMessage.author.bot && msg.includes('hello')){
            message.reply('Previous message found');
        } 
  });
```

Comment: I can't find the function `fetchMessages` in the discord.js documentation, can you provide a source to where you got that from?

Comment: it's deprecated, from 11.0 I believe

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you using?

Here it is in latest version if interested,

```js
const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('712147984464478251');
//could also use channel.messages.cache.find
channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
    const lastMessage = messages.filter(m => m.content.includes("includes") && !m.author.bot).last();
    if (lastMessage) {
        message.reply('Previous message found');
    }
});
```

Comment: I haven't used discord.js since around 2018 or so and some of this code was from my old bot which obviously is very outdated now. I tried out your code and it seemed to work well except I noticed the bot continued to chat the same line. I believe this is because the fetch is looping so it continously replies. How should I change this to only respond once?

Comment: It's not a stream/collector, it just gathers all the messages and then runs `.then` once, might be something else in your code, that repeats it